# How to hide the elements on the onload of a page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, show-hide

Following is my HTML code:

```
<div id="entrancelist">
        <h2 class="heading">favourite questions</h2>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="98%" style="padding:5px;" align="center">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="sub_name" id="" >
                  <div style="height:auto; overflow:hidden; width:100%;">



                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top" width="70%">
                          <b>Question 4.</b></td>
                          <td valign="top" align="left" width="30%">
                          <b><a href ="#" style="margin-right:0px;" class="fav_que" id="93041">Remove From Favourite Question</a></b></td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

                          </td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top"> 
                          <b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>The angel between <img align="middle" class="Wirisformula" src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=527931a5749cffe312c126871736b88d.png"><br></p></body></html>
                                                                            </td>
                        <td valign="bottom" align="right"><b>QUE93041</b></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr class="question_info">                    
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Show Answers</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr> 
                      </td>                      
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

90o

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

between 0o and 180o

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

180o only 

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

none of these

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 2   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                        </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>    
  </div>
```

Here I'm showing the questions, it's available options and correct answer. I'm hiding and showing the available options and correct answers on the click of a hyperlink. The code for it is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".show-ans").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:last").is(":visible")){
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
        $(this).html("Show Answers");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").show();
        $(this).html("Hide Answers");
    }
  });
});
```

The above code is also working fine. My issue is when the page loads these things should be hidden for all the questions and on the click of a hyperlink it should hide if it's showing and it should be shown when it's hidden. Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: You should hide this with css, otherwise the answers will flash on the page when it initially loads on slow computers/browsers.

Comment: just toggle a class...

Comment: Kevin B is right, you need to add display: hidden; to the answer's css and not hide them on page load using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Hide them with static CSS so they cannot be seen when the page is loading. Your code is just adding an event handler for the click event, but, until someone clicks on that link, your elements will always be visible.

Comment: In your CSS files, if you've got any. And if you don't, you should, to separate presentation from content.

Answer (score 0):

without change your logic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-ans").each(function() {
        if($(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:last").is(":visible")){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
            $(this).html("Show Answers");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").show();
            $(this).html("Hide Answers");
        }
      });
    });
```

but this kind of task has a better solution: `toggle()` or `toggleClass()`.

toggle swap between hide and show.

However a best practice it's `toggleClass()` to add and remove a css class.
In you case you can simply start with 2 pars like:

```
<p id="answersyes">Show Ansers</p>
<p id="answerno" class="hideToUser">Hide Answrs</p>
```

in your css file:

```
.hideToUser {
  display: none; 
}
```

With a css class you'll be able to extend the solution to set a background color, a bold text and so on.
More, apply styles to your html it's simple without do nothing with javascript (so manutention will be increased).

Answer (score 0):

Just as you've done with 'question_info', you could add a class 'answer_info'. In the css you add: `.answer_info{display: none;}` or `.answer_info{visibility: hidden;}`. In the show answer-function you use jquery to remove the class `$('.answer_info').removeClass('answer_info');`